# Put App in editable state

Tags: ios, app-store, iad

I am an app available for sale at the app store. I would like to change my iAd settings but I receive this message:

"You can only change your iAd Settings when the latest version of your app is in an editable state."

How do I put my app into an editable state?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's when you've submitted an app update

Comment: So every time we need to make changes to the iAd Settings we need to release an update for review?  That does not seem to make sense.  Plus, it could take several days for the update to be approved and it really is no update to the app.

Comment: It's while the app is waiting review. They do the same thing for changing tags for your app, you can only do that with a pending update.

Comment: Ok, so here is the whole issue, my app is available for sale.  I did test it and it did show test ads.  When I submitted it, I am almost positive I clicked the has ads button. But, no ads are showing.  It just got approved for sale this last night, so 2 questions:  1) Does it take time before ads show?   2) Is there a easy to verify that I checked the has ads button?

Comment: If tests ads show in testing, they will work in production. UNLESS your phone is jailbroekn or using iOS 6. If either of those are true, even in the app store release, you will see Test Ads.

Comment: Yes, test ads work perfect.  My phone is not jail broken and I am using iOS 5... so, soul it be it just needs some time to start working?

Comment: Last comment, if test ads work perfectly, then make sure you're using the app store release and not another dev version from Xcode. Try deleting and reinstalling the app from the app store. Ads should work if they are turned on.

Comment: LOL, I guess that is a question, how do I verify that ads are turned on?  Does the fact that the test ads were showing up mean ads are turned on?  Also, in iTunesConnect, under the iAd network link, I do see the app at the bottom showing "Test Ads"

Comment: You will see this in messages in iAd Network when your app is running ads correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit a new binary for the application with iAds included in it as an update